# How to decode input data with ABI using golang?

Tags: golang

There is a tool on npm [ethereum-input-data-decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder). And yes, i can read input data as hex.

And i hope that i can decode transaction's inputdata using golang.
For example 0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000067f883a42031215622e0b84c96d0e4dca7a3ce810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e100

thx.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/dec8bba9d4c5fcb3dd7e51f0f794b3e895c7f52d/accounts/abi

Comment: Have you solved your problem? @Hundred lee. I also want to parse transaction input but confused how to begin

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33975)

Answer (score 10):

took me a bit of time to figure out that myAbi.Unpack(...) unpacks output of a method or event. In your case (and mine) we want to unpack the inputs. Here is a working code sample

```
// example of transaction input data
txInput := "0xa5142faa00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"

// load contract ABI
abi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(myContractAbi))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// decode txInput method signature
decodedSig, err := hex.DecodeString(txInput[2:10])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// recover Method from signature and ABI
method, err := abi.MethodById(decodedSig)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// decode txInput Payload
decodedData, err := hex.DecodeString(txInput[10:])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// create strut that matches input names to unpack
// for example my function takes 2 inputs, with names "Name1" and "Name2" and of type uint256 (solidity)
type FunctionInputs struct {
    Name1 *big.Int // *big.Int for uint256 for example
    Name2 *big.Int
}

var data FunctionInputs

// unpack method inputs
err = method.Inputs.Unpack(&data, decodedData)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(data)
```

Comment: Can someone guide me what imports I need for this code? 2019's libraries look very different from 2021 ...  what is "abi" in this context?

Comment: @nicocesar "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"

Comment: 404 Grr.... help us out please

Comment: wow, it's so good

Answer (score 4):

This is isn't tested, but it'd be sort of like this:

```
myAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(abiJsonString))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var ifc map[string]interface{}
encodedData := "0x00123..."
err := myApi.Unpack(&ifc, "someMethod", encodedData)
if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
}
```

You'd also have to iterate through all the ABI methods and plug it into the second argument to the `abi.Unpack` method to find which method the data belongs to.

Comment: How to decode the entire input using the ABI and get a json as an output?

Comment: WTF is abi here?

Comment: @pguardiario https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/accounts/abi

Answer (score 3):

```
    if reader, err := os.Open("token.abi"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        if tokenAbi, err := abi.JSON(reader); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
            encodedData := "a9059cbb00000000000000000000000067f883a42031215622e0b84c96d0e4dca7a3ce810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e100"
            decodeData, err := hex.DecodeString(encodedData)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            // a9059cbb == transfer
            if method, ok := tokenAbi.Methods["transfer"]; ok {
                params, err := method.Inputs.Unpack(decodeData[4:])
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                log.Println(params)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation on how this solves the problem.

Comment: `decodeData[4:]` works like a magic

Answer (score 1):

Since `geth` is written in go, it makes some sense there's probably an official package for this. Looking into the official `go-ethereum` library, there's a package [called abi there](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/dec8bba9d4c5fcb3dd7e51f0f794b3e895c7f52d/accounts/abi), you might be able to use that.

Comment: sorry, I know this package .But i dont't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with the solution:

```
myAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(abiJsonString))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var ifc map[string]interface{}
encodedData := "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000067f883a42031215622e0b84c96d0e4dca7a3ce810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e100"
decodeData, _ := hex.DecodeString(encodedData)
err := myApi.Unpack(&ifc, "someMethod", decodeData[4:])
if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What is abi????

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example about decode input data and output data

https://gist.github.com/crazygit/9279a3b26461d7cb03e807a6362ec855